# "onReadyToSubscribe" not called after application loaded

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

MobileFirst 7.1

My code is not called onReadyToSubscribe function after the application initialization. The server adapter are connected successfully.

```
if (WL.Client.Push) {   
//Invoke the onReady Subscribe method
WL.Client.Push.onReadyToSubscribe = function() {
alert("Push :: onReadyToSubscribe");
    //WL.Logger.debug("registerEventSourceCallback");

    WL.Client.Push.registerEventSourceCallback(
            "myPush", 
            "PushAdapter", 
            "PushEventSource", 
            pushNotificationReceived);

    //Check its already event based push notification subscribed or not 
    var isSubscribed = WL.Client.Push.isSubscribed("myPush");
    if (!isSubscribed) {
        //do event source subscribe
        doSubscribe();
    }
};
}

 function doSubscribe() {
  WL.Client.Push.subscribe("myPush", {
    onSuccess: doSubscribeSuccess,
    onFailure: doSubscribeFailure
  });
}

function doSubscribeSuccess() {
     alert("PUSH :: doSubscribeSuccess");
}

function doSubscribeFailure() {
  alert("Push :: doSubscribeFailure");
}
```

Comment: Give a lot more details than this:
a) What is your Worklight/MFP version?
b) Android/iOS/Windows?
c) Emulator or real device?
d) Is your application push enabled?

Comment: WorkLight version : 7.1.0.00.20160401-2103

Comment: <pushSender key="AIzaSyD9WCRoUYGkDkSQv5K-qkTleN9QFjdm0" senderId="8302556330"/>

Comment: Please provide client side logs - logcat . Is the line "alert("Push :: onReadyToSubscribe");" firing?

Comment: @SampathKumar, please respond

Comment: @vivin k It is not, that is the issue.

Comment: Can you provide the logs please. Client and server ( when the issue is recreated)

Comment: Yep, got the issue, native plugins <push> is missing in the config file now am getting the ready called but facing different issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in this question was the push plug-in missing from the application's config.xml file. Presumably the application was re-built correctly so that the push plug-in was added this time around.